# Handling paragraphs inside list items with a custom CSS content

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-content

This is how a paragraph looks like inside a non-styled list item (`<li>`):

[image]

```
<li>
  <p>
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
  </p>
</li>
```

However, when using a custom list style type it looks like this:

[image]

The HTML for this is:

```
<li class="docs-test">
  <p>
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
    hehehe
  </p>
</li>
```

The CSS is:

```
.docs-test {
  color: red;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.docs-test::before {
  content: '\2022 ';
  color: #828282;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.docs-test p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I know that for this particular custom list style type I could use list-style-image. However, I have other customs list style types for the which I cannot use list-style-image.

How can I make it so that paragraphs inside list items with a custom CSS content list style type don't jump to the beginning of the next "line"? The goal is for these custom list style lists to handle paragraphs the same way regular lists without styling do.

http://jsbin.com/kimilaniga/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: So, you need to put bullets for every word inside p tag?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal no, I just want the entire paragraph to *not* jump as if there was a `<br>` tag before it. Basically I want it to look like the first image. I could easily replicate the first image by using `display: inline` for list items but then it wouldn't work with multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Got it.Sorry,my system did'nt support that img file.You have used span in the js demo but here you have used p tag?

Comment: Yes, I might have changed the demo while playing around to use a span instead of a p, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of realizing the styling that you want.

Use absolute positioning to place the generated content from the `::before` pseudo-element to the left of the left edge of the `<li>` block element.

First, you need to add `position: relative` to the `.docs-test` CSS rule to allow the pseudo-element to be positioned with respect to the `li` parent block.

Second, add `position: absolute` and appropriate `top` and `left` offset values to get the styling that you want.

You also need to reset the margins on the `p` element to zero.

```css
.docs-test {
  color: red;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.docs-test::before {
  content: '\2022 ';
  color: #828282;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px dotted gray; /* for demo only */
  width: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  top: 0;
}

.docs-test p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>
      hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe
    </p>
  </li>

  <li class="docs-test">
    <p>
      hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe hehehe
      </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Could you pls elaborate on why this jump happens?